# "how to deal with the problem" vs "what to do with the problem"

Tags: grammar, verbs, idioms, phrasal-verbs

1. He knows ***how*** to deal with the problem.
2. He knows **what** to do with the problem.

Can we switch between **" how"** and **" what"**? Why and why not?

Comment: The idioms are _deal with_ and _do about_.

Comment: @John Lawler,  Some grammar books say " how to do with + object" is incorrect. They say "do" is a transitive verb and it should be used with " what" not "how". I don't agree and doubt about it, but I can't find authoritative demonstrations;even Collins and OED have little specific definitions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not responsible for what some grammar books say. Some grammar books will say anything at all. It's not clear what you want to say (or write) and who you're addressing it to. _What to do about the problem_ is not a sentence; it could be a title. English grammar applies to spoken sentences, not to title cards; there is no "correct" or "incorrect" except in context.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I surely know " what to do about  the problem" isn't a sentence, as you can see in the heading of my post.

Comment: “What to do with the problem” invites such things as ignoring it, burying it, and leaving it for the next person to *deal* with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both possibilities amount to the same thing: being aware of the various steps to be taken amounts to knowing how to deal with the problem and vice-versa. However, in the second sentence, on top of the change of verb, I would use a different preposition.

*For instance (there are others)*

- He knows what to do about the problem.
- He knows what to do regarding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
He knows how to deal with the problem.
He knows what to do *with (sic) the problem.
```

There are grammatical issues here. Apart from that,  they do not mean the same thing; there is a nuanced difference in usage of adverbs  in  these two cases.

***How*** is an adverb meaning "the manner in which".

***What*** describes the exact action, object, or idea.

Example:

> The LORD shall ***smite thee*** *with a consumption, and with a fever, and with an inflammation, and with an extreme burning, and with the sword, and with blasting, and with mildew;* and they shall pursue thee until thou perish. 
> Deuteronomy 28:22

"God will smite you." describes the action. i.e. ***"What"*** he will do.

***How will he smite you?***

"...with consumption, and with a fever, etc.." describes the manner. i.e ***"How"***, or the fashion in which  he will do it.

---

A more recent example is seen in the ultimate resolution of **"the Jewish Problem".**

Hitler mandated the removal of all "mongrel races" from German national territory. He determined "what to do", but he built a layer of flunkies to insulate himself from his nefarious actions.

Himmler, and especially Heydrich, decided the most economic means i.e. the gas showers, hence the "How to do it".

---

In this century, Mark Zuckerburg might describe the direction he wants FaceBook to go, but it is left up to many subordinates to choose the method, if you believe what comes out of [Face Book PR...](https://www.facebook.com/journalismproject/facebook-oversight-board-for-content-decisions-overview)

Comment: @ Cascabel, Your unique demonstration, illustration and description as well, add to this topic with deeper connotations.